# The meaning of phrase of "To wilf"

Tags: meaning

What does "to wilf" mean? Apparently it means to browse webs pointlessly but I can't confirm that anywhere. Is this even an English word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's an acronym](http://www.inclusionmark.co.uk/index.php/food-for-thought/walt-and-wilf-do-you-know-shorthand-2/) that means "What I am Looking For"/"What am I Looking For". Also, it's an inappropriate term comparable to MILF, so I'm not sure I'll be using it anytime soon myself.

Comment: Also a archaic variant of *willow*.

Comment: How is _wilf_ inappropriate or comparable to _milf_, apart from rhyming with it? _Milf_ is inappropriate (in some contexts) because of what it stands for; _wilf_ stands for nothing even remotely inappropriate.

Comment: "Man, have you seen that chick Joe married in Vegas, she's definitely a WILF."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It stands for the same as MILF with "Wife" replacing "Mother". See: Urban Dictionary. (Yay, citations.)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I thought you were talking about the “what am I looking for?” acronym being inappropriate; didn’t realise you were talking about two separate kinds of _wilf_.

Comment: Are we actually saying that these ... er ... words aren't ... er words?

Answer (score 0):

Same as "To nick", in the sense of "While you were in the shower, I wilfed one of your cigarettes".

Comment: Hi! That's quite interesting. Where did you hear that?